# Project allocation optimization with tricky constraint

Tags: optimization, algorithms, linear-programming

I have an allocation problem that should be straightforward, except that it has very specific constraints. I want to assign approximately 300 students to 170 projects in pairs - so that each project has exactly 2 students assigned to it. Each student ranks their 10 favourite projects (1 to 10), and I want to maximise the ranking of projects.

I can do this using a Hungarian algorithm, treating the ranking as a cost and minimising the overall cost. The pairing is fine, because there are only slightly more projects than required, and several projects are not chosen by any students. So I drop 20 un-chosen projects to give exactly twice as many projects as students, list each project twice and run it through a standard Hungarian algorithm, which I have in R. Problem solved!

Except... there are two types of students (I'll call them A and B). And pairs of students on projects have to be of the same type, so that a project can have either 2 'A' students or 2 'B' students, but not one of each. There are roughly equal numbers of A and B students. The obvious solution is to assign the As first and then the Bs. But when allocating the As I have far more projects than students and they don't automatically pair up. Also, the Bs will end up with lower choice projects than the As, which isn't fair.

So can anyone think of either a solution or an adequate work-around? Ideally something I can run in R easily, but I'm happy to do a bit of programming.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a min cost flow problem with additional constraints. I would suggest linear programming.

Let $x_{ij}^k$ a boolean variable that equals $1$ if and only if student $i$ ($=1...300$) of type $k$ (A or B) is assigned to project $j$ ($=1…170$), and let $c_{ij}$ be the rank of project $j$ by student $i$.

You want to maximize 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{300}\sum_{j=1}^{170}\sum_{k\in\{A,B\}}c_{ij}x_{ij}^k
$$
subject to

- Each project has a pair of students: 
  $$\sum_{i=1}^{300}\sum_{k\in\{A,B\}}x_{ij}^k = 2 \quad \forall j=1,…,170$$
- Each student has exactly one project:
  $$\sum_{j=1}^{170}\sum_{k\in\{A,B\}}x_{ij}^k = 1 \quad \forall i=1,…,300$$
- Students assigned to projects have to be of the same type:
  $$
  x_{ij}^k\le \sum_{\ell\neq i} x_{\ell j}^k \quad \forall j=1,…,170 \quad \forall k \in \{A,B\}
  $$
- Variables are binary:
  $$
  x_{ij}^k \in \{0,1\}
  $$

Comment: This solutions does not respect the additional constraint that only students of the same type (A or B) may be assigned to a project.

Comment: Yes you are right, for some reason I forgot to take this into account, I will think about it. I think this can be solved with linear programming.

Comment: I have edited the according linear program.

Comment: The program seems correct to me. However, I am not sure how long it will take to compute a solution since this is now an integer program which *might* be very slow.

Comment: Indeed, it is no longer a pure minimum cost flow algorithm, it could be hard to solve. I am not sure there are other options if we want the optimal solution. Note however that the structure of the problem makes it a good candidate for a column generation approach: sub problems would be pure minimum cost flow problems easy to solve, and the master problem would deal with the last group of constraints. This is quite a lot of work if one has no experience integer programming though.

Comment: Thanks - the formulatoin of this looks like it matches my situation but I don't understand how the costraint making sure that the two students assigned to a project are of the same type (A or B). Couldn't you instead insist that the sum over all i, all j and all k in {A} sums to 0 or 2 and that the same sum for all k in {B} sums to 0 or 2?

Comment: Assuming you mean sum over all $i$, all $k \in A$, $\forall j$, how would you express the "sums to 0 or 2" part ? 
What the constraint says is: if a given variable $x_{ij}^k$ equals 1, than another variable $x_{\ell j}^k$ also has to be set to one.

Comment: Sorry, just tried to edit this, but I took too long - I see now that the constraint making sure that the two students assigned to a project are of the same type (A or B), works by insisting that if a student of type k is assigned to a project (the left hand side of the inequality), then another student of type k has to be assigned (the right hand side)? But, crucially, how do I program this?

Comment: You have many options. My personal preference is with the PuLp module in Python (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PuLP). Incredibly simple, well documented, with many examples.